# The application called an interface that was Marshalled for different thread error when using MangementObjectSearcher

Tags: c#, winforms, exception, hook

I have used MouseKeyboardActivityMonitor to set some limitations for user activities for example disable mouse.

www.codeproject.com/Articles/7294/Processing-Global-Mouse-and-Keyboard-Hooks-in-C

I have these code in my form

```
public partial class MyForm:Form
{
     KeyboardHookListener kl;
     MouseHookListener ml;
     MyForm:Form()
    {
        ml = new  MouseHookListener( new GlobalHooker());
        ml.Enabled=true;
    }
    private void MyForm_Load
    {
        ml.MouseDownExt += ml_MouseDownExt;
        // And same thing for Click or ...
    }
    private void ml_MouseDownExt( object sender,MouseEventExtArgs  e)
    {
          e.Handled= true;
          // I have got hard disk serial number here
          string sn = HardDisk.Serial;
    }
```

}

And code of HardDisk.Serial

```
ManagementObjectSearcher s= new  ManagementObjectSearcher(" SELECT *...");
foreach( var wmi in s.Get())
{
}
```

I get error when I click on MyForm .

When I built my solution and run it manually
I get this error

> ```
> The application called an interface that was Marshalled for different thread
> ```

Stack:

> ```
> at system.management.MangementException.ThrowWithExtendedInfo( Exception e)
> at system.management.MangementObjectSearcher.Get()
> at HardDisk.Get_serial()
> at  ml_MouseDownExt( object sender,MouseEventExtArgs  e)
> at     MouseKeyboardActivityMonitor.MouseHookListener.InvokeMouseEventHandlerExt(EventHandler'1 handler,MouseEventExtArgs e)
> ```

But when I run my solution with visual studio an exception will throw at HardDisk.serial 
at s.Get line , I get this

Error:

> ```
> Managed debugging assistant ' DisconnectedContext' 
> Has detected a problem in 'my app Name.exe'
> Transition into com context 0xa4206 for this runtime   callable wrapper failed with following error :
> an outgoing call can't be made since the application is dispatching an input asynchronous call
> ```

It obvious that two error is from MangementObjectSearcher class.I get serial number in another place in MyForm .errors just occurres when get serial in ml_MouseDownExt method or other method that has been added to events of GlobalHooker .I have seen msdn. In inheritance hierarchy of MangementObjectSearcher I see System.MarshalByRefObject

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.management.managementobjectsearcher(v=vs.110).aspx

I don't know that it is related to these errors or not

How should I avoid these errors?

Comment: It isn't very clear what you did to get this MDA, it is certainly very bad.  Neither the snippets nor the Codeproject.com project give any hints.  Go back to your Program.cs file and verify that the Main() method still has the [STAThread] attribute.  And never, *never* create a form object on a worker thread unless you really know what you're doing.  Just about nobody does.

Answer (score 0):

Your hook callback isn't being raised on the right thread.  And that's just the first problem.  Wrap it in a BeginInvoke and all will be well:

```
private void ml_MouseDownExt( object sender,MouseEventExtArgs  e)
{
      e.Handled= true;

      var wrongThread = new Action(()=>
      {
          // I have got hard disk serial number here
          string sn = HardDisk.Serial;
          //put anything else you were planning on doing with sn here
      }
      BeginInvoke(wrongThread, null);
}
```

The second problem is that you're trying to interact with a COM object in the handler for a global hook.  BeginInvoke should get around that nicely by delaying it for a few microseconds.

Don't forget to make sure Dispose gets called on that global hook.  Closing the app isn't enough unless you like rebooting often.